# Redshift with SSIS/SSDT

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Has anyone been successful using Amazon Redshift as a source or destination ODBC component in SQL Server Data Tools 2012?

I've installed the PostgreSQL drivers provided by Amazon and have successfully tested a connection in the Windows ODBC driver administrator but keep running into arcane error messages when I choose my saved DSN and try to pull a table listing.

Answer (score 3):

Redshift is based on quite an old version of Postgres (8.0). Postgres has changed quite a bit since then and the Postgres tools have changed with it. When downloading any tools to use with Redshift you will probably need to use previous versions from several years ago.

The table listing problem is particularly annoying but I have yet to find a version of `psql` that can properly list Redshift tables. As an alternative you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables to find this kind of info, and in my opinion this is what SSIS/SSDT should be doing by default.

I would not expect SSIS to be able to load data into Redshift reliably, i.e. create a Redshift destination. This is because Redshift does not *really* support `INSERT INTO` as a way to load data. If you use `INSERT INTO` you will only be able to load ~10 rows per second. Redshift can only load data quickly from S3 or DynamoDB using the `COPY` command.

It's a similar story for all other ETL tools I've tried, notably the open source tools Pentaho PDI (aka Kettle) and Talend Open Studio. This is particularly annoying in Talend's case as they have Redshift components but they actually try to use `INSERT INTO` for loading. Even Amazon's own ETL tool Data Pipeline does not yet have support for Redshift as 'node'.

Comment: it is old message, but just for information for whom will search - even in 2017 (and 2016 as I remember) Talend already use COPY for load Redshift from S3

Answer (score 1):

I have been successful. Try installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the PostgreSQL ODBC drivers.

Also, in your Project Properties under 'Configuration Properties' > 'Debugging', set 'Run64BitRuntime' to False.

You can also try specifying the connection string in Connection Manager. For example:
    Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};
    server=redshiftdb.d113klxjd4ac.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com;uid=;database=;port=5432